# function score groovy script not returning any result

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch, lucene

my query is

```
{
    "query": {
    "function_score": {
    "functions": [{
    "script_score": {
                "lang": "groovy",
                "script_file": "category-score",
                "params": {
                  "my_modifier": "doc['category'].value"
                }
              }
    },
    {
    "script_score": {
                "lang": "groovy",
                "script_file": "popularity-score",
                "params": {
                  "my_modifier": "doc['popularity'].value"
                }
              }
    },
    {
    "script_score": {
                "lang": "groovy",
                "script_file": "type-score",
                "params": {
                  "my_modifier": "doc['finder_type'].value"
                }
              }
    }
    ],
    "query": {
    "filtered": {
    "query": {"multi_match": {
    "query": "rent,buy",
    "fields": ["category","categorytags"]
    }},"filter": {
    "bool" : {"must": [{"terms" : { "city": ["mumbai"] }}]}
    },"_cache" : true
    }
    },
    "score_mode": "sum",
    "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
    }}
```

and my four script files looks like

```
(my_modifier == 'rent,buy' ? 10 : 0)

log(my_modifier1.value)

(my_modifier2 > 0 ? 20 : 0)
```

I am trying to calculate the score of matching documents in the function score with three script_score functions.
My scripts are getting compiled on startup as i can see in logs but it don't return me any result.ES version is 1.6.0. 
Also how can i enable inline/dynamic scripting on with ES-1.6.0 as i tried around with many settings changes in elasticsearch.yml as ES as comeup with some breaking changes with 1.6.0 release for scripting module.

Comment: try checking only with the main query to see if you actually get hits ? Also would be helpful if you provide a few example documents ? FWIW the script score  should have params my_modifier,my_modfier1,my_modifier2

Comment: yes, that parameter is fine, i pasted it as mistake.Found out the issue.the query with multi-match is not working for 1.6.0 for comma seperated values or multi valued.but the same is working for 1.4.2. I will confirm today and will open a issue on github today.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
              "my_modifier": "doc['finder_type'].value"
```

Params should be a value and not a script.

Comment: can't we pass value from the document field as parameter as a script parameter?

Comment: You can pass the field name and then use doc[passedParameter].value to access the value